# Run a .exe file from BAT file and wait for the execution before running next set of commands

Tags: git, batch-file, siebel

I have a bat file ready for my GIT integration with Siebel tools. But i need to add a tool execution before GIT checkin
So how can i run that tools .exe and then wait for the application to close. And after that continue with git checkin.

Comment: Start by reading: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: You will have to put in a loop in the bat file, to check current processes and check if tools.exe is still running.

Comment: How can we do that, as in how to check if its running, please share commands to start and wait.

Answer (score 1):

Use `call`.

Example:

```
call tools.exe
```

Good source: https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

From this source:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> CALL [drive:][path]filename [parameters]
> CALL :label [parameters]
> CALL internal_cmd
> ```

Also from this source:

> The Microsoft help for the CALL command rather misleadingly states
>   "Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent
>   batch program" it is true that the parent does not STOP, but it does
>   PAUSE while the second script runs.

---

I just wrote a simple *.bat* file that looks like this:

```
echo Hello.
call C:\Siebel\Tools\BIN\siebdev.exe /c "C:\Siebel\Tools\bin\enu\tools.cfg"
echo Waiting for close.
pause
```

When I ran it, it output `Hello.`, then it output the `call` line and opened my Siebel tools.  I "tooled" around in Tools doing some things I normally do for a couple of minutes.  All the while the command line window output still only showed the `call` line.  Only after I did a *File > Exit* from Tools did the batch file output the `Waiting for close.` line, and then pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start /wait` for that like in

```
start /wait my.exe
```